# What are some reliable MMS Gateways

Tags: sms, gateway

This isn't a directly programming related question, but I wasn't sure where else to ask this and since it is for a technical project I'm working on, I hope it isn't closed down.

This project requires users to be able to send text and images via text to a website. I have been told to make use of an SMS gateway that supports MMS (for the image part).

What are some reliable MMS gateways, I tried searching but wasn't sure which ones are reliable and which aren't.

Comment: What country are you based in?

Answer (score 0):

[www.openmarket.com](http://www.openmarket.com)

Answer (score 0):

This industry changes a lot. Two of the biggest as-of-today are Ericsson and Mobile Messenger.